# Bifurcate/Split Numbers to lower granularity pandas | Integers rounding off

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

1. DF1: Products and their respective sales projections like below
2. DF2: Product wise sub components with respective percentage contributions

I want to divide product projections to its sub components into integers basis given ratios without disturbing overall total. (Rounding up and down accordingly)

[Here are dataframes with desired output for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWJIW.png)

How can i do this with pandas and python?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on='Product Name', how='left')
df3['Projections'] = df3['Projections']*df3['Contribution']

del df3['Product Name']
del df3['Contribution']
```

Comment: if the answer works for you, do consider accepting the answer, it serves as an encouragement for contributors. thanks!